# Google Glass Samples Won't Resolve

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I think I may have the Google Glass SDK installed in Eclipse incorrectly. I followed all the quick start instructions and downloaded all the different samples provided. All of them have the following type of error where a significant number of times cannot be resolved to a type.

```
AESObfuscator cannot be resolved to a type
R cannot be resolved to a type
```

And so for many other items. Eclipse tells me I have the correct version of Android installed. 4.0.3. There might also be some connection problems, but those have not been consistent.

I believe that I have everything installed correctly, but cannot run any of the samples because of this. If anyone has seen this in Google Glass or another Android project it would be so helpful. If you need more detail please let me know as well!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your R.java is not building.
So Change your projects build target to **Glass Development Kit Sneak Peak (4.0.3)**. Then clean your project. this might solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I check the project build target under Android in Properties, it says that the build Target is the Glass Dev Kit already. On the bottom area under library there is a red X and a question mark through. Could that be a problem? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @jmbjones Would you please attach a snapshot with the question so that  i can have a better understanding of your question